# Wrong keyboard input language on Windows 8 lock screen

Tags: windows, windows-8, lock-screen

I have two keyboard languages configured on my Windows 8 machine: English (United States) and Español (España). The default language is English (United States), but when I start my computer, sometimes the lock screen shows me another language (Español Latinoamérica) by default. I don't have that language configured.

Are the lock screen languages configured in another place? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In you Control Panel (Desktop Mode), there's the way:

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language\Advanced settings
```

You will see a link in the first section called:

- *Apply languages settings to the welcome screen, system accounts, and new user accounts*.

Click on it, it will open a dialog window with two (2) sections. In the first one, click on *Copy settings...* then check the two (2) checkboxes in the bottom of the resulting window. Then *OK*. It will apply your current settings to the lock screen and etc.

Comment: I know this had been answered by Frederick but for those who are complaining why they can't override the language, you might not be using a PRO version. No, you can't change that no matter how you try. I even dug down to its registry, but it won't let me save the language hex. Go buy a Pro/Enterprise version then.