# Use English as an input language for Windows 8 lock screen by default

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout, lock-screen

I have two input languages configured on my Windows 8 machine. The default language is English, but when I lock my computer, the lock screen sometimes uses another language for input, so I have to retype my password. It happens when another language is selected when I lock my computer. I want the lock screen to always use English as an input language by default.

There is [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/488932/wrong-keyboard-input-language-on-windows-8-lock-screen) that only asks about starting computer, not locking. The accepted answer to that question does not solve my problem.

Comment: Keyboard layout and system language are different things

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: indeed. Windows uses the term "input language", so do I.

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply your desired language to the lock screen.

1. In the Control Panel, switch to *Time, Language and Region, Language*.
2. Move the desired layout to the top.
3. On the left, click *Advanced settings*.
4. Click the *Apply language settings for Welcome page, system accounts and new user accounts* link.
5. Click the *Copy settings...* button.

Comment: I have already done so. English is already on top and the settings are copied. It worked with Windows 7 but does not work with Windows 8.